# Is there a way to get the remainder of a list slice without copying the list

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, split

With a string in python, I can easily get the remainder of a slice by doing this

```
my_string = 'pythonisawesome'
print(my_string.replace(my_string[6:8], ''))

print(my_string)
```

This Outputs

```
pythonwesome
pythonisawesome
```

I don't need to copy the string because python strings are immutable so the first result is discarded since a name is not assigned to it and my_string remains unchanged

But this operation is not possible for lists since lists are mutable, for example:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
del my_list[6:8] # or my_list[6:8] = ''

print(my_list)
```

Outputs

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10]
```

Also I also find it a bit strange that `my_list` is modified while I delete the slice, I believe slices are supposed to cut out a part of the list as a copy and not act the way indexes do

because doing:

```
my_otherlist = my_list[:]
```

creates a new copy of the list(when it's not nested) and can be modified without affecting the original list

The main point I'm driving at is that python should have a method that takes slices and returns the remainder of the slice

like `list.chopoff[::]`

Maybe there's a method but I didn't come across it in the standard library.

Comment: I don't understand *Python should have a method that takes slices and returns the remainder of the slice*. Would you mind adding an example?

Comment: You are mixing things up. `replace` has **nothing** to do with slices, its first argument need not be a slice, is just any string: it's a pattern matching algorithm that finds the given substring and replaces it with the corresponding value. And no: that kind of algorithms are only provided for strings, `list`s and other types only have stuff like `index` but nothing built-in like `replace(sublist, other)`. You have to implement that yourself.

Comment: what would be the point of `del my_list[6:8]` if it did not remove elements from the list?

Comment: @GeorgSchölly, there's already an example there, i would like to take a slice but instead of getting back the slice i want what was not sliced

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i know it's supposed to get deleted, but why does `[:]` create a shallow copy of a list which cannot be modified by operations done on the first list. it's like python is cheating :)

Comment: To me, Python's behavior makes sense if you think of slices as extended indices: `del my_list[a:b]` works just the same way `del my_list[c]` does. Same thing for accessing elements `sub_list = my_list[a:b]` is the same as `element = my_list[c]`. The syntax to copy `[:]` works because slices can leave out one side, defaulting to the ends of the list.

Comment: I think that is something you would have to ask the python devs, if you wanted a new list you would have to do it manually like `new = my_list[:6] + my_list[8:]`  or some variation, you could also roll your own implementation

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a new list you would have to do it manually like

```
 my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

 print(my_list[:6] + my_list[8:])
 print(my_list)
```

It gives Output  like

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```